# Xamarin Forms - iOS - Back button title

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to change the back button text in the NavigationPage *after* the constructor of the page ?

I have a list of buttons inside a page which are used to change the current language and want to update the back button’s title according to the selected language.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/272076/#Comment_272076

Bind the Title's page property to a string and update the string depending on your selected language.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This answer might help other people but it's not working for me since I want to translate the "Back" text, and, therefore, I need this text to be different than the page title.